# the for loop is not executing inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have been trying to get the all from a table name as forms so everything goes fine but here I have columns like question1,question2,question3 upto 20 so I want to get that too for which I am using a for loop inside a foreach loop so foreach loop worked out perfectly but the for loop didn't work out so if you people can please take a look at my code as :

```
<?php

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM forms") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

$resultset = array();
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $resultset[] = $rows;
}

$form_questions_no = $resultset['form_questions_no'];

?>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Form Name</th>
<th>Form Questions No</th>
<th>Form Questions</th>
<th>Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($resultset as $result) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $result['form_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['form_questions_no']; ?></td>
<td><?php for($i=0;$i<$form_questions_no;$i++) { $i_query = $i+1; echo "<p>".$result['question'.$i_query]."</p>"; } ?>
</td>
<td>
<form method="post" action="delete_client_query.php">
<button type="submit" name="delusername" class="btn btn-primary" value="<?php echo $result['Username'] ?>">Delete</button></form></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

so if you people can take a look at my code please as...! and let me know what I am doing wrong please so I will be very kindful..!

Comment: where did you define $form_questions_no?

Answer (score 1):

Because , in your loop `for($i=0;$i<$form_questions_no;$i++)` the variable

```
$form_questions_no
```

is undefined, its actually

```
$result['form_questions_no']
```

So your loop runs from 0 to 0, which is 0 times :)

**After your edit**

Your variable still has the wrong value and this answer still explains your problem. Your variable definition says

```
$form_questions_no = $result['form_questions_no'];
```

But there Is no such thing as `$result` in your code, that `$result`, according to your code, is: `$query`

Comment: I have already defined it above in code it is also a column which has values in numbers..! questions is updated please with query added..! please have a look back again..!

Comment: See the edit, problem still remains the same :)

Comment: Check please...I have updated the code and still that problem..! when I remove the while loop and assigning to array in start so then in foreach loop I get illegel string ofset error and then It seems to be working fine..!

Comment: Wow sorry im not a debugging machine :) That error still is the same. `$resultset[] = $rows;` That means resultset has many rows and hence you cant just say `$resultset["bla_bla"];` Why don't you go ahead and `echo $form_questions_no;` to find out if what i'm saying is wrong. Sorry but I wont contribute more.

Comment: Thanks for your time I really fixed that by using `$result['form_questions_no']` in for loop as : `for($i=0;$i<$result['form_questions_no'];$i++)`